# Dapper select inner join mapping to a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dapper

Assume I have the following tables

```
  Table Products
  --------
  Id (int)
  Name (varchar)
  BrandId (int)

  Table Brands
  -----------
  Id (int)
  BrandName (varchar)
```

and the following classes in CSharp

```
public class Product{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public string Name { get;}
   public ProductBrand Brand { get;}
}
public class ProductBrand{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public string BrandName { get;}
}
```

How can i `Select inner join` the two tables and map to the `ProductBrand` model with all its properties in dapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working code, please make changes like below,

```
    public class Product{
   public int Id { get; set;}
   public string ProductName { get;}
}
public class Brand{
   public int BrandId { get; set;}
   public string BrandName { get;}
   public IList<Product>Products { get;}
}

var sql ="SELECT Id, ProductName, BrandId, BrandName FROM Brand B INNER JOIN Product  P ON B.BrandId=P.BrandId"
var products = connection.QueryAsync<Brand, Product, Brand>(sql, 
(brand, product) => {
if(brand.Products==null)
{
    brand.Products = new List<Product>;
}
    brand.Products.Add(product);
    return brand;
},
splitOn: "BrandId");
```

Comment: Your code is similar to yair below in that it uses multiple parameters in the query function but it also seems very different. Why does your solution work better than Yairs?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Query method like below:

```
using (IDbConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
{
    string sql = "SELECT Products.Id, BrandName FROM Products INNER JOIN Brands ON Products.BrandId = Brands.Id";
    var result = connection.Query<ProductBrand>(sql);
}
```

Comment: i want to get a product model though. this gets me a ProductBand model

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use it by creating a procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetProducts

AS
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        Products.Id,
        Brands.BrandName
    FROM Products
        INNER JOIN
        Brands ON Products.BrandId  = Brands.Id

END
GO
```

- 

```
using (IDbConnection db = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString"))
{
    
   var productBrands = db.Query<ProductBrand>("GetProducts").ToList();
    
}
```

Comment: Does this approach actually work because the selected answer also uses the same sql statement but in raw form rather than stored procedure and the query method requires multiple parameters to do the binding.

Answer (score 0):

Relationships management in Dapper goes the other way- Each Brand should have a list of Products.

so the classes should look like this:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string Name { get;}
}

public class Brand
{
    public int Id { get; set;}
    public string BrandName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

and then you can query like this:

```
var products = connection.QueryAsync<Product, Brand, Product>(sql, 
(product, brand) => {
    product.Brand = brand;
    return product;
},
splitOn: "BrandId");
```